# Placing all menus in a .c file

Tags: c

Is is incorrect to create all program menus in their own separated .c files?
I´m creating a small inventory program and since it will use quite a few menus i´m wondering if that is acceptable.

I´ll be using linked lists to enventually access the information in binary files, to create, edit, delete and consult the information related to clientes, suppliers, employes and stocks.

So rather than having all menus in the main.c, I´m not sure wether to place each menu in it´s own .c file or all menus in one menu.c file.

To me it´s easier placing each menu in it´s own .c file since that makes it easy to see the code but will create a lot of .c files.

Comment: Not enough information here to provide a good answer.

Comment: But i´m wondering if that is bad programming, since I´ll be creating several menus problably around 10, that will be a lot of .c files with mostly one function.

Comment: By *far* not enough information. For instance, if all of your menu functions basically do the same, you could do with just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function showMenu() that ask the user what option he wants. Per example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char showMenu()
{
    char option;
    printf("===== Access the information =====\n"
           "A) Binary files\n"
           "B) Create\n"
           "C) Edit\n"
           "D) Delete\n"
           "Q) Quit\n"
           "Your option: ");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    return option;
}

int main(void)
{
    int exit = 1;
    do
    {
        switch(toupper(showMenu()))
        {
            case 'A':
                // Function A
                break;
            case 'B':
                // Function B
                break;
            case 'C':
                // Function C
                break;
            case 'D':
                // Function D
                break;
            case 'Q':
                exit = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("No valid input");  // handle the error
        }
        printf("\n");
    } while(exit);
    return 0;
}
```

It's a good practice to separate the code, but creating one file for each function is probably too much. In your situation, creating a functions.h with functions.c and main.c is a good idea.

Comment: it wouldn't decrease performance if it was done with #include "submenu-a.h" ... that's what its there for.

Comment: Indeed, because they are compiled languages.

Comment: The example above is very close to what my main menu is. But then for the "create" option I´ll need to show a menu with what the user can create (cliente, suplier, product, employee, sale, purchase), and each option a new menu for data input by user. Thank you for all your help I initially thought is was a much simpler process of just creating multiple simple menus, but I´ll try to conserve as much code as possible even thouth I´ll need 15 different menus.